# Calling function each time qt windows gain focus

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have a mainwindow which in there is a Qtableview by clicking on insert record I go to other modal windows to add record when I add record and close the second windows I come back to main windows but the qtableview doesn't show the new record that is added. The record is in database.

I already make this somehow work with :

```
    void MainWindow::showEvent( QShowEvent* event ) {
    QWidget::showEvent( event );
    updTbl();
}
```

But it only works when windows get minimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling activate/deactivate events as follows will give you the desired behaviour

```
// overloading event(QEvent*) method of QMainWindow
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent* e)
{
    switch (e->type()) 
    {
    case QEvent::WindowActivate:
    // gained focus
    //Update Table
    break;

    case QEvent::WindowDeactivate:
    // lost focus
    break;
    };
    return QMainWindow::event(e);
}
```

Ref: https://gist.github.com/01walid/2276009

Comment: The answers that mainly depend on a link are not quality answers because if the link is broken your answer will be unusable

Answer (score 1):

QMainWindow has also two event handler from QWidget

[void QWidget::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusInEvent)

[void QWidget::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusOutEvent)

If you use QtCreator, go to your mainwindow.h and search the line "class MainWindow : public QMainWindow". Right click on QMainWindow -> Refactoring -> Insert virtual function. That's an easy way to find which virtual functions exist and that can be overloaded, you can select focusInEvent and focusOutEvent from there.